# Configuring a standard single server TFS 2013 with SharePoint 2013 and SSRS for reporting

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, tfs, ssas, reporting

Is following scenario possible?

We have got TFS 2013 installed as a standard single server. This server has got the SQL db.

We have got SharePoint 2013 installed on another machine.

Now we want to integrate TFS 2013 with SharePoint 2013 along with SSRS and SSAS for reports, etc.

Please guide whether this is possible or we need to install TFS via Advanced mode again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, you can integrate your existing TFS single server deployment with your external SharePoint server assuming you have the necessary permissions.

MSDN: Verify your SharePoint installation
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd578601(v=vs.120).aspx

MSDN: Set up remote SharePoint
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh548140(v=vs.120).aspx

Cheers

Comment: It would be much better to repost relevant parts of the articles that you reference rather than simply link.  Links go dead! :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, David, I'm new to SO and it won't allow me to post images etc.  Once I get a few points I'll put some more detailed posts together.

Answer (score 0):

Adding SSRS and SSAS is relatively simple too and can be on the same server as TFS or a different one.

MSDN: Add a report server
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn148128.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Martin Hinshelwood has a couple of useful blog posts on this subject too:

http://nakedalm.com/integrate-sharepoint-2013-with-team-foundation-server-2013/
http://nakedalm.com/integrate-reporting-and-analyses-services-with-team-foundation-server-2013/

*sorry for the multiple answers, new account and SO doesn't trust me to post 5 links yet! :)